# Set header for dataTable "Show entries" and "Search"" input as center fixed for responsive viewport

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design, datatables

I need help with my code. Currently it's working nicely on desktop screen but however on mobile, I need the `Show entries` and `Search` field location as center fixed like the `select box` above. Right now if I scrolled the table horizontally, both input field will also move which is not what I wanted.

Here's the html code:

```
<div class="center"><select name="act" onchange="javascript:void(document.list.submit());"><option value="kfc">KFC</option><option value="sub">SUBWAY</option><option value="pzh">Pizza Hut</option></select></div>

<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
  <table id="example" class="display">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>First name</th>
        <th>Last name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
        <th>Extn.</th>
        <th>E-mail</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Tiger</td>
        <td>Nixon</td>
        <td>System Architect</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2011/04/25</td>
        <td>$320,800</td>
        <td>5421</td>
        <td>t.nixon@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Garrett</td>
        <td>Winters</td>
        <td>Accountant</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>63</td>
        <td>2011/07/25</td>
        <td>$170,750</td>
        <td>8422</td>
        <td>g.winters@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ashton</td>
        <td>Cox</td>
        <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>66</td>
        <td>2009/01/12</td>
        <td>$86,000</td>
        <td>1562</td>
        <td>a.cox@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cedric</td>
        <td>Kelly</td>
        <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>2012/03/29</td>
        <td>$433,060</td>
        <td>6224</td>
        <td>c.kelly@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Airi</td>
        <td>Satou</td>
        <td>Accountant</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>33</td>
        <td>2008/11/28</td>
        <td>$162,700</td>
        <td>5407</td>
        <td>a.satou@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Brielle</td>
        <td>Williamson</td>
        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2012/12/02</td>
        <td>$372,000</td>
        <td>4804</td>
        <td>b.williamson@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Herrod</td>
        <td>Chandler</td>
        <td>Sales Assistant</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>59</td>
        <td>2012/08/06</td>
        <td>$137,500</td>
        <td>9608</td>
        <td>h.chandler@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Rhona</td>
        <td>Davidson</td>
        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>55</td>
        <td>2010/10/14</td>
        <td>$327,900</td>
        <td>6200</td>
        <td>r.davidson@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Colleen</td>
        <td>Hurst</td>
        <td>Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>39</td>
        <td>2009/09/15</td>
        <td>$205,500</td>
        <td>2360</td>
        <td>c.hurst@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Sonya</td>
        <td>Frost</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>2008/12/13</td>
        <td>$103,600</td>
        <td>1667</td>
        <td>s.frost@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jena</td>
        <td>Gaines</td>
        <td>Office Manager</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>2008/12/19</td>
        <td>$90,560</td>
        <td>3814</td>
        <td>j.gaines@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Quinn</td>
        <td>Flynn</td>
        <td>Support Lead</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>2013/03/03</td>
        <td>$342,000</td>
        <td>9497</td>
        <td>q.flynn@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Charde</td>
        <td>Marshall</td>
        <td>Regional Director</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>36</td>
        <td>2008/10/16</td>
        <td>$470,600</td>
        <td>6741</td>
        <td>c.marshall@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Haley</td>
        <td>Kennedy</td>
        <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>43</td>
        <td>2012/12/18</td>
        <td>$313,500</td>
        <td>3597</td>
        <td>h.kennedy@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Tatyana</td>
        <td>Fitzpatrick</td>
        <td>Regional Director</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>19</td>
        <td>2010/03/17</td>
        <td>$385,750</td>
        <td>1965</td>
        <td>t.fitzpatrick@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Michael</td>
        <td>Silva</td>
        <td>Marketing Designer</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>66</td>
        <td>2012/11/27</td>
        <td>$198,500</td>
        <td>1581</td>
        <td>m.silva@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Paul</td>
        <td>Byrd</td>
        <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>64</td>
        <td>2010/06/09</td>
        <td>$725,000</td>
        <td>3059</td>
        <td>p.byrd@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Gloria</td>
        <td>Little</td>
        <td>Systems Administrator</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>59</td>
        <td>2009/04/10</td>
        <td>$237,500</td>
        <td>1721</td>
        <td>g.little@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Bradley</td>
        <td>Greer</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>41</td>
        <td>2012/10/13</td>
        <td>$132,000</td>
        <td>2558</td>
        <td>b.greer@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Dai</td>
        <td>Rios</td>
        <td>Personnel Lead</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>35</td>
        <td>2012/09/26</td>
        <td>$217,500</td>
        <td>2290</td>
        <td>d.rios@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jenette</td>
        <td>Caldwell</td>
        <td>Development Lead</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>2011/09/03</td>
        <td>$345,000</td>
        <td>1937</td>
        <td>j.caldwell@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Yuri</td>
        <td>Berry</td>
        <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>40</td>
        <td>2009/06/25</td>
        <td>$675,000</td>
        <td>6154</td>
        <td>y.berry@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Caesar</td>
        <td>Vance</td>
        <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>21</td>
        <td>2011/12/12</td>
        <td>$106,450</td>
        <td>8330</td>
        <td>c.vance@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Doris</td>
        <td>Wilder</td>
        <td>Sales Assistant</td>
        <td>Sidney</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>2010/09/20</td>
        <td>$85,600</td>
        <td>3023</td>
        <td>d.wilder@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Angelica</td>
        <td>Ramos</td>
        <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>47</td>
        <td>2009/10/09</td>
        <td>$1,200,000</td>
        <td>5797</td>
        <td>a.ramos@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Gavin</td>
        <td>Joyce</td>
        <td>Developer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>42</td>
        <td>2010/12/22</td>
        <td>$92,575</td>
        <td>8822</td>
        <td>g.joyce@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jennifer</td>
        <td>Chang</td>
        <td>Regional Director</td>
        <td>Singapore</td>
        <td>28</td>
        <td>2010/11/14</td>
        <td>$357,650</td>
        <td>9239</td>
        <td>j.chang@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Brenden</td>
        <td>Wagner</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>28</td>
        <td>2011/06/07</td>
        <td>$206,850</td>
        <td>1314</td>
        <td>b.wagner@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Fiona</td>
        <td>Green</td>
        <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>48</td>
        <td>2010/03/11</td>
        <td>$850,000</td>
        <td>2947</td>
        <td>f.green@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Shou</td>
        <td>Itou</td>
        <td>Regional Marketing</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>2011/08/14</td>
        <td>$163,000</td>
        <td>8899</td>
        <td>s.itou@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Michelle</td>
        <td>House</td>
        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
        <td>Sidney</td>
        <td>37</td>
        <td>2011/06/02</td>
        <td>$95,400</td>
        <td>2769</td>
        <td>m.house@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Suki</td>
        <td>Burks</td>
        <td>Developer</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>53</td>
        <td>2009/10/22</td>
        <td>$114,500</td>
        <td>6832</td>
        <td>s.burks@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Prescott</td>
        <td>Bartlett</td>
        <td>Technical Author</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>27</td>
        <td>2011/05/07</td>
        <td>$145,000</td>
        <td>3606</td>
        <td>p.bartlett@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Gavin</td>
        <td>Cortez</td>
        <td>Team Leader</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>2008/10/26</td>
        <td>$235,500</td>
        <td>2860</td>
        <td>g.cortez@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Martena</td>
        <td>Mccray</td>
        <td>Post-Sales support</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>46</td>
        <td>2011/03/09</td>
        <td>$324,050</td>
        <td>8240</td>
        <td>m.mccray@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Unity</td>
        <td>Butler</td>
        <td>Marketing Designer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>47</td>
        <td>2009/12/09</td>
        <td>$85,675</td>
        <td>5384</td>
        <td>u.butler@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Howard</td>
        <td>Hatfield</td>
        <td>Office Manager</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>51</td>
        <td>2008/12/16</td>
        <td>$164,500</td>
        <td>7031</td>
        <td>h.hatfield@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Hope</td>
        <td>Fuentes</td>
        <td>Secretary</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>41</td>
        <td>2010/02/12</td>
        <td>$109,850</td>
        <td>6318</td>
        <td>h.fuentes@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Vivian</td>
        <td>Harrell</td>
        <td>Financial Controller</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>62</td>
        <td>2009/02/14</td>
        <td>$452,500</td>
        <td>9422</td>
        <td>v.harrell@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Timothy</td>
        <td>Mooney</td>
        <td>Office Manager</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>37</td>
        <td>2008/12/11</td>
        <td>$136,200</td>
        <td>7580</td>
        <td>t.mooney@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>Bradshaw</td>
        <td>Director</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>65</td>
        <td>2008/09/26</td>
        <td>$645,750</td>
        <td>1042</td>
        <td>j.bradshaw@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Olivia</td>
        <td>Liang</td>
        <td>Support Engineer</td>
        <td>Singapore</td>
        <td>64</td>
        <td>2011/02/03</td>
        <td>$234,500</td>
        <td>2120</td>
        <td>o.liang@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Bruno</td>
        <td>Nash</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>38</td>
        <td>2011/05/03</td>
        <td>$163,500</td>
        <td>6222</td>
        <td>b.nash@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Sakura</td>
        <td>Yamamoto</td>
        <td>Support Engineer</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>37</td>
        <td>2009/08/19</td>
        <td>$139,575</td>
        <td>9383</td>
        <td>s.yamamoto@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Thor</td>
        <td>Walton</td>
        <td>Developer</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2013/08/11</td>
        <td>$98,540</td>
        <td>8327</td>
        <td>t.walton@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Finn</td>
        <td>Camacho</td>
        <td>Support Engineer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>47</td>
        <td>2009/07/07</td>
        <td>$87,500</td>
        <td>2927</td>
        <td>f.camacho@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Serge</td>
        <td>Baldwin</td>
        <td>Data Coordinator</td>
        <td>Singapore</td>
        <td>64</td>
        <td>2012/04/09</td>
        <td>$138,575</td>
        <td>8352</td>
        <td>s.baldwin@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Zenaida</td>
        <td>Frank</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>63</td>
        <td>2010/01/04</td>
        <td>$125,250</td>
        <td>7439</td>
        <td>z.frank@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Zorita</td>
        <td>Serrano</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>56</td>
        <td>2012/06/01</td>
        <td>$115,000</td>
        <td>4389</td>
        <td>z.serrano@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jennifer</td>
        <td>Acosta</td>
        <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>43</td>
        <td>2013/02/01</td>
        <td>$75,650</td>
        <td>3431</td>
        <td>j.acosta@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cara</td>
        <td>Stevens</td>
        <td>Sales Assistant</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>46</td>
        <td>2011/12/06</td>
        <td>$145,600</td>
        <td>3990</td>
        <td>c.stevens@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Hermione</td>
        <td>Butler</td>
        <td>Regional Director</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>47</td>
        <td>2011/03/21</td>
        <td>$356,250</td>
        <td>1016</td>
        <td>h.butler@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lael</td>
        <td>Greer</td>
        <td>Systems Administrator</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>21</td>
        <td>2009/02/27</td>
        <td>$103,500</td>
        <td>6733</td>
        <td>l.greer@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jonas</td>
        <td>Alexander</td>
        <td>Developer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>2010/07/14</td>
        <td>$86,500</td>
        <td>8196</td>
        <td>j.alexander@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Shad</td>
        <td>Decker</td>
        <td>Regional Director</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>51</td>
        <td>2008/11/13</td>
        <td>$183,000</td>
        <td>6373</td>
        <td>s.decker@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Michael</td>
        <td>Bruce</td>
        <td>Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>Singapore</td>
        <td>29</td>
        <td>2011/06/27</td>
        <td>$183,000</td>
        <td>5384</td>
        <td>m.bruce@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Donna</td>
        <td>Snider</td>
        <td>Customer Support</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>27</td>
        <td>2011/01/25</td>
        <td>$112,000</td>
        <td>4226</td>
        <td>d.snider@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Full code: http://jsfiddle.net/jg5xaz06/6/

Run the code. Switch to mobile viewport and scroll the table horizontally: http://jsfiddle.net/jg5xaz06/6/show

Please help me solved this responsive design problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution:

HTML:

```
<html>

  <body>


    <div class="center"><select name="act" onchange="javascript:void(document.list.submit());"><option value="kfc">KFC</option><option value="sub">SUBWAY</option><option value="pzh">Pizza Hut</option></select></div>

      <table id="example" class="display">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>First name</th>
            <th>Last name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
            <th>Extn.</th>
            <th>E-mail</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Tiger</td>
            <td>Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
            <td>5421</td>
            <td>t.nixon@datatables.net</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Garrett</td>
            <td>Winters</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011/07/25</td>
            <td>$170,750</td>
            <td>8422</td>
            <td>g.winters@datatables.net</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Ashton</td>
            <td>Cox</td>
            <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>2009/01/12</td>
            <td>$86,000</td>
            <td>1562</td>
            <td>a.cox@datatables.net</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Cedric</td>
            <td>Kelly</td>
            <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2012/03/29</td>
            <td>$433,060</td>
            <td>6224</td>
            <td>c.kelly@datatables.net</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Airi</td>
            <td>Satou</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>33</td>
            <td>2008/11/28</td>
            <td>$162,700</td>
            <td>5407</td>
            <td>a.satou@datatables.net</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Brielle</td>
            <td>Williamson</td>
            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2012/12/02</td>
            <td>$372,000</td>
            <td>4804</td>
            <td>b.williamson@datatables.net</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Herrod</td>
            <td>Chandler</td>
            <td>Sales Assistant</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>59</td>
            <td>2012/08/06</td>
            <td>$137,500</td>
            <td>9608</td>
            <td>h.chandler@datatables.net</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Rhona</td>
            <td>Davidson</td>
            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>55</td>
            <td>2010/10/14</td>
            <td>$327,900</td>
            <td>6200</td>
            <td>r.davidson@datatables.net</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Colleen</td>
            <td>Hurst</td>
            <td>Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>39</td>
            <td>2009/09/15</td>
            <td>$205,500</td>
            <td>2360</td>
            <td>c.hurst@datatables.net</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Sonya</td>
            <td>Frost</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>2008/12/13</td>
            <td>$103,600</td>
            <td>1667</td>
            <td>s.frost@datatables.net</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Jena</td>
            <td>Gaines</td>
            <td>Office Manager</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>2008/12/19</td>
            <td>$90,560</td>
            <td>3814</td>
            <td>j.gaines@datatables.net</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Quinn</td>
            <td>Flynn</td>
            <td>Support Lead</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2013/03/03</td>
            <td>$342,000</td>
            <td>9497</td>
            <td>q.flynn@datatables.net</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Charde</td>
            <td>Marshall</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>36</td>
            <td>2008/10/16</td>
            <td>$470,600</td>
            <td>6741</td>
            <td>c.marshall@datatables.net</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Haley</td>
            <td>Kennedy</td>
            <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>43</td>
            <td>2012/12/18</td>
            <td>$313,500</td>
            <td>3597</td>
            <td>h.kennedy@datatables.net</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Tatyana</td>
            <td>Fitzpatrick</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>19</td>
            <td>2010/03/17</td>
            <td>$385,750</td>
            <td>1965</td>
            <td>t.fitzpatrick@datatables.net</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Michael</td>
            <td>Silva</td>
            <td>Marketing Designer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>2012/11/27</td>
            <td>$198,500</td>
            <td>1581</td>
            <td>m.silva@datatables.net</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Paul</td>
            <td>Byrd</td>
            <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>64</td>
            <td>2010/06/09</td>
            <td>$725,000</td>
            <td>3059</td>
            <td>p.byrd@datatables.net</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Gloria</td>
            <td>Little</td>
            <td>Systems Administrator</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>59</td>
            <td>2009/04/10</td>
            <td>$237,500</td>
            <td>1721</td>
            <td>g.little@datatables.net</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Bradley</td>
            <td>Greer</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>41</td>
            <td>2012/10/13</td>
            <td>$132,000</td>
            <td>2558</td>
            <td>b.greer@datatables.net</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Dai</td>
            <td>Rios</td>
            <td>Personnel Lead</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>35</td>
            <td>2012/09/26</td>
            <td>$217,500</td>
            <td>2290</td>
            <td>d.rios@datatables.net</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Jenette</td>
            <td>Caldwell</td>
            <td>Development Lead</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>2011/09/03</td>
            <td>$345,000</td>
            <td>1937</td>
            <td>j.caldwell@datatables.net</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Yuri</td>
            <td>Berry</td>
            <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>40</td>
            <td>2009/06/25</td>
            <td>$675,000</td>
            <td>6154</td>
            <td>y.berry@datatables.net</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Caesar</td>
            <td>Vance</td>
            <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>2011/12/12</td>
            <td>$106,450</td>
            <td>8330</td>
            <td>c.vance@datatables.net</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Doris</td>
            <td>Wilder</td>
            <td>Sales Assistant</td>
            <td>Sidney</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>2010/09/20</td>
            <td>$85,600</td>
            <td>3023</td>
            <td>d.wilder@datatables.net</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Angelica</td>
            <td>Ramos</td>
            <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>47</td>
            <td>2009/10/09</td>
            <td>$1,200,000</td>
            <td>5797</td>
            <td>a.ramos@datatables.net</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Gavin</td>
            <td>Joyce</td>
            <td>Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>42</td>
            <td>2010/12/22</td>
            <td>$92,575</td>
            <td>8822</td>
            <td>g.joyce@datatables.net</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Jennifer</td>
            <td>Chang</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>Singapore</td>
            <td>28</td>
            <td>2010/11/14</td>
            <td>$357,650</td>
            <td>9239</td>
            <td>j.chang@datatables.net</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Brenden</td>
            <td>Wagner</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>28</td>
            <td>2011/06/07</td>
            <td>$206,850</td>
            <td>1314</td>
            <td>b.wagner@datatables.net</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Fiona</td>
            <td>Green</td>
            <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>48</td>
            <td>2010/03/11</td>
            <td>$850,000</td>
            <td>2947</td>
            <td>f.green@datatables.net</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Shou</td>
            <td>Itou</td>
            <td>Regional Marketing</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>2011/08/14</td>
            <td>$163,000</td>
            <td>8899</td>
            <td>s.itou@datatables.net</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Michelle</td>
            <td>House</td>
            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
            <td>Sidney</td>
            <td>37</td>
            <td>2011/06/02</td>
            <td>$95,400</td>
            <td>2769</td>
            <td>m.house@datatables.net</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Suki</td>
            <td>Burks</td>
            <td>Developer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>53</td>
            <td>2009/10/22</td>
            <td>$114,500</td>
            <td>6832</td>
            <td>s.burks@datatables.net</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Prescott</td>
            <td>Bartlett</td>
            <td>Technical Author</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>27</td>
            <td>2011/05/07</td>
            <td>$145,000</td>
            <td>3606</td>
            <td>p.bartlett@datatables.net</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Gavin</td>
            <td>Cortez</td>
            <td>Team Leader</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2008/10/26</td>
            <td>$235,500</td>
            <td>2860</td>
            <td>g.cortez@datatables.net</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Martena</td>
            <td>Mccray</td>
            <td>Post-Sales support</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>46</td>
            <td>2011/03/09</td>
            <td>$324,050</td>
            <td>8240</td>
            <td>m.mccray@datatables.net</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Unity</td>
            <td>Butler</td>
            <td>Marketing Designer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>47</td>
            <td>2009/12/09</td>
            <td>$85,675</td>
            <td>5384</td>
            <td>u.butler@datatables.net</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Howard</td>
            <td>Hatfield</td>
            <td>Office Manager</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>51</td>
            <td>2008/12/16</td>
            <td>$164,500</td>
            <td>7031</td>
            <td>h.hatfield@datatables.net</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Hope</td>
            <td>Fuentes</td>
            <td>Secretary</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>41</td>
            <td>2010/02/12</td>
            <td>$109,850</td>
            <td>6318</td>
            <td>h.fuentes@datatables.net</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Vivian</td>
            <td>Harrell</td>
            <td>Financial Controller</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>62</td>
            <td>2009/02/14</td>
            <td>$452,500</td>
            <td>9422</td>
            <td>v.harrell@datatables.net</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Timothy</td>
            <td>Mooney</td>
            <td>Office Manager</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>37</td>
            <td>2008/12/11</td>
            <td>$136,200</td>
            <td>7580</td>
            <td>t.mooney@datatables.net</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Jackson</td>
            <td>Bradshaw</td>
            <td>Director</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>65</td>
            <td>2008/09/26</td>
            <td>$645,750</td>
            <td>1042</td>
            <td>j.bradshaw@datatables.net</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Olivia</td>
            <td>Liang</td>
            <td>Support Engineer</td>
            <td>Singapore</td>
            <td>64</td>
            <td>2011/02/03</td>
            <td>$234,500</td>
            <td>2120</td>
            <td>o.liang@datatables.net</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Bruno</td>
            <td>Nash</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>38</td>
            <td>2011/05/03</td>
            <td>$163,500</td>
            <td>6222</td>
            <td>b.nash@datatables.net</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Sakura</td>
            <td>Yamamoto</td>
            <td>Support Engineer</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>37</td>
            <td>2009/08/19</td>
            <td>$139,575</td>
            <td>9383</td>
            <td>s.yamamoto@datatables.net</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Thor</td>
            <td>Walton</td>
            <td>Developer</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2013/08/11</td>
            <td>$98,540</td>
            <td>8327</td>
            <td>t.walton@datatables.net</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Finn</td>
            <td>Camacho</td>
            <td>Support Engineer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>47</td>
            <td>2009/07/07</td>
            <td>$87,500</td>
            <td>2927</td>
            <td>f.camacho@datatables.net</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Serge</td>
            <td>Baldwin</td>
            <td>Data Coordinator</td>
            <td>Singapore</td>
            <td>64</td>
            <td>2012/04/09</td>
            <td>$138,575</td>
            <td>8352</td>
            <td>s.baldwin@datatables.net</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Zenaida</td>
            <td>Frank</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2010/01/04</td>
            <td>$125,250</td>
            <td>7439</td>
            <td>z.frank@datatables.net</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Zorita</td>
            <td>Serrano</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>56</td>
            <td>2012/06/01</td>
            <td>$115,000</td>
            <td>4389</td>
            <td>z.serrano@datatables.net</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Jennifer</td>
            <td>Acosta</td>
            <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>43</td>
            <td>2013/02/01</td>
            <td>$75,650</td>
            <td>3431</td>
            <td>j.acosta@datatables.net</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Cara</td>
            <td>Stevens</td>
            <td>Sales Assistant</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>46</td>
            <td>2011/12/06</td>
            <td>$145,600</td>
            <td>3990</td>
            <td>c.stevens@datatables.net</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Hermione</td>
            <td>Butler</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>47</td>
            <td>2011/03/21</td>
            <td>$356,250</td>
            <td>1016</td>
            <td>h.butler@datatables.net</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Lael</td>
            <td>Greer</td>
            <td>Systems Administrator</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>2009/02/27</td>
            <td>$103,500</td>
            <td>6733</td>
            <td>l.greer@datatables.net</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Jonas</td>
            <td>Alexander</td>
            <td>Developer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>2010/07/14</td>
            <td>$86,500</td>
            <td>8196</td>
            <td>j.alexander@datatables.net</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Shad</td>
            <td>Decker</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>51</td>
            <td>2008/11/13</td>
            <td>$183,000</td>
            <td>6373</td>
            <td>s.decker@datatables.net</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Michael</td>
            <td>Bruce</td>
            <td>Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Singapore</td>
            <td>29</td>
            <td>2011/06/27</td>
            <td>$183,000</td>
            <td>5384</td>
            <td>m.bruce@datatables.net</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Donna</td>
            <td>Snider</td>
            <td>Customer Support</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>27</td>
            <td>2011/01/25</td>
            <td>$112,000</td>
            <td>4226</td>
            <td>d.snider@datatables.net</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
  </body>

</html>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
    "initComplete": function (settings, json) {  
    $("#example").wrap("<div style='overflow:auto; width:100%;position:relative;'></div>");            
  },
  });
});
```

CSS

```
.center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/jg5xaz06/16/

Reference :
http://sforsuresh.in/datatables-header-body-not-aligned/